# Rotate and move text element in SVG

Tags: svg, text, rotation

How can I place text in svg as shown below such that:

- the text is rotated by -90 deg
- the mid point of the text (intersection of diagonal lines) has a fixed point P after transformation (for example `P.x = 200`, `P.y = 300`)

[image: Text]

On my attempts I was able to rotate the element, however I cannot seem to position it correctly. I even experimented with base lines, center of rotations etc. but I am completely lost now. Thank you <3

`<text transform="rotate(-90, 0, 0) translate(200, 300)" dominant-baseline="central">Some Text</text>`

Comment: try using `dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"`  for the text and also try translating first and then rotating

Comment: Thank you. Came to the same conclusion now. If you want, you can post this as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I finally solved it. Sorry for wasting your time.

```
<rect fill="red" width="100" height="100"></rect>
<text transform="translate(100, 100) rotate(-90)" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 18px;">Some Text</text>
```

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

As **@enxaneta** commented :

> try using dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" for the text
> and also try translating first and then rotating

Since the order of performing transformations is from right to left. Rotation first, then translate

*Initial state without transformations The red circle is the center of the text*

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid">  

<g >     
<circle cx="104" cy="37.5" r="4" fill="red" />
<text id="txt1" x="104" y="50"  font-family="sans-serif" font-size="36px" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" > Some Text </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

*Position of the text after transformation*

```css
.txt1 {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
 text-anchor:middle;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
fill:black;
}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid">  

<g>      
<circle cx="104" cy="37.5" r="3" fill="red" />
<text class="txt1" x="104" y="50" > Some Text </text>
</g>

<g transform=" translate(200, 300) rotate(-90, 0, 0) " >     
<circle cx="104" cy="37.5" r="3" fill="red" />
<text class="txt1" x="104" y="50" > Some Text </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

### Update

*animation of rotation and movement of text*

```css
.txt1 {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
 text-anchor:middle;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
fill:black;
}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid">  
<g>
<g class="txt1" >    
<circle cx="104" cy="37.5" r="3" fill="red" />
<text  x="104" y="50"  font-family="sans-serif" font-size="36px" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" > Some Text 
</text>    
                       <!-- animation of text rotation -->
  <animateTransform id="anR" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" additive="sum"  to="-90,0,0" begin="1s;anT.end+1.5s" dur="2s" fill="freeze"   /> 
</g>      
                        <!-- animation of moving text -->
   <animateTransform id="anT" attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="sum"  to="200,200" begin="anR.begin" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  /> 
</g>
</svg>
```